# python geocode.replace(" ", "") Internal server error

Tags: python, geocoding, str-replace

I need help with the `string.replace(" ", "")`

I am using google geocode and it is returning the geocode as

`(-1.2890979, 36.90147) --------- return latitude,longitude`

I have stored the geocode in a variable called `location`

I want to send the coodinates without the brackets and without the space
but `location.replace` give a 500 Internal server error. 
Any suggestions on what i can do to correct this?

Comment: That's a tuple, not a string. Thus, you can't replace any characters. Instead, the parentheses and comma are just for representation; the coordinates themselves are just a pair of floating point numbers.

Comment: Why do you use ‘foursquare’ tag?

Comment: Have you stored the value of `latitude, longitude` in location? That's a tuple and should be accessed as `location[0]` for latitude and `location[1]` for longitude

Comment: @Evert How can i assign a variables as lat,long so i can pass it on to another api?

Comment: @KosukeOgawa It's because I need to pass the lat,long to the Foursquare Add Venue endpoint. Now, am getting the response {u'meta': {u'errorType': u'param_error', u'code': 400, u'requestId': u'5aa116731ed2190ba3c830b5', u'errorDetail': u'll must be of the form XX.XX,YY.YY (received 36.90147)'}, u'response': {}}

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla How can i combine the two so that i can pass it to Foursquare api in the ll parameter which must not have space or the brackets.

Comment: Well, what does that api accept? Just a string perhaps? Can you add a link and a relevant quote from the documentation to your question? It must be documented somewhere. `XX.XX,YY.YY` is ambiguous.

Comment: @Evert Not much is given but an example is given : {44.3,37.2} The description : {required unless near is provided. Latitude and longitude of the user’s location. Optional if using intent=global} The doc is here: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/search

Comment: You should add that information into your question, not in (just) a comment.

Comment: But have you tried send it as a "xxx.xxx,yyy.yyy" string?

Comment: @Evert I never knew about tuples before this post. But after some research, i found that i can convert the tuple into string by using str(tuple)...With this, yes, i can send the coordinates as string by replacing the unnecessary characters from the tuple (i.e. space & brackets)

Comment: Well, `str(sometuple)` will give you the space and parentheses. Just use string formatting: `"{},{}".format(*sometuple)` should do it.

Answer (score -1):

The coodinates from google geocode,

(-1.2890979, 36.90147) --------- return latitude,longitude

are not string but tuple.

That means you cannot use the replace function. Instead convert the tuple using str(tuple) where tuple is the location variable.

Then use the replace function to remove the unnecessary characters.

Comment: Don't use `str.replace()`; just apply string formatting for the tuple elements.